# Using Spring Boot For replacing Corda server giving privacy salt should be 32 bit exception

Tags: spring-boot, corda

I tried migration from Corda Server to Spring Boot.I referred to Joel's Project(Corda official) in Kotlin but getting this exception when trying to use rpcOps.

```
RPCClientProxyHandler.artemisMessageHandler - RPC reply arrived to unknown RPC ID RpcRequestId(toLong=2111196934580277300), this indicates an internal RPC error.
        [ERROR] 2018-02-02T07:54:05,227 [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] client - AMQ214000: Failed to call onMessage
    com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Privacy salt should be 32 bytes.
    Serialization trace:
    legalIdentitiesAndCerts (net.corda.core.node.NodeInfo)
    value (net.corda.core.utilities.Try$Success)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:144) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.read(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:147) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:813) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:731) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.read(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:147) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:813) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:209) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:152) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.withContext(SerializationScheme.kt:191) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.access$withContext(SerializationScheme.kt:152) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1.execute(SerializationScheme.kt:206) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.run(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:61) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:205) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:115) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:53) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:115) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:95) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:67) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:115) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.RPCApi$ServerToClient$Companion.fromClientMessage(RPCApi.kt:234) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.artemisMessageHandler(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:242) ~[corda-rpc-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.access$artemisMessageHandler(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:65) ~[corda-rpc-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler$start$3.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:192) ~[corda-rpc-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler$start$3.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:65) ~[corda-rpc-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandlerKt$sam$MessageHandler$cbde6789.onMessage(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt) ~[corda-rpc-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:997) ~[artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:49) ~[artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1120) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$ExecutorTask.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:101) [artemis-commons-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_144]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_144]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Privacy salt should be 32 bytes.
        at net.corda.core.contracts.PrivacySalt.<init>(Structures.kt:272) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.DefaultKryoCustomizer$PrivacySaltSerializer.read(DefaultKryoCustomizer.kt:188) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.DefaultKryoCustomizer$PrivacySaltSerializer.read(DefaultKryoCustomizer.kt:182) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:813) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:731) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        ... 34 more
```

Below is my RPConnector:

```
private CordaRPCOps rpcOps;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        System.out.println("RPConnector [host=" + host + ", username=" + username + ", password=" + password
                + ", rpcPort=" + rpcPort + "]");
        NetworkHostAndPort rpcAddress = new NetworkHostAndPort(host, Integer.valueOf(rpcPort));
        CordaRPCClient rpcClient = new CordaRPCClient(rpcAddress);
        CordaRPCConnection rpcConnection = rpcClient.start(username, password);
        rpcOps = rpcConnection.getProxy();
    }

    public CordaRPCOps getRPCops() {
        return rpcOps;
    }
```

The connection happens successfully but when I try to use RPC connector I get the following error:
Below is my controller. When I try to get all  nodes I get the error:

```
@Autowired
private RPConnector rpcOps;
private final List<String> serviceNames = ImmutableList.of("Controller", "Network Map Service");

@GetMapping("/allnodes")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Map<String, List<CordaX500Name>> getAllNodes() {
    List<NodeInfo> nodeInfoSnapshot = rpcOps.getRPCops().networkMapSnapshot();
    return ImmutableMap.of("allnodes",
            nodeInfoSnapshot.stream().map(node -> node.getLegalIdentities().get(0).getName()).filter(
                    name -> !name.equals(rpcOps.getRPCops().nodeInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0).getName())
                            && !serviceNames.contains(name.getOrganisation()))
                    .collect(toList()));
}
```

Thank you.

Update on Error, There is a null pointer exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializedBytes.getHash(SerializationAPI.kt)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializedBytes.<init>(SerializationAPI.kt:201)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$serialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:233)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$serialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:152)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.withContext(SerializationScheme.kt:191)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.access$withContext(SerializationScheme.kt:152)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$serialize$1.execute(SerializationScheme.kt:221)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$serialize$1.execute(SerializationScheme.kt:152)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.run(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:61)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.serialize(SerializationScheme.kt:220)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$serialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:119)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$serialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:95)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:53)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$serialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:119)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$serialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:95)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:67)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.serialize(SerializationScheme.kt:119)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationAPIKt.serialize(SerializationAPI.kt:191)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationAPIKt.serialize$default(SerializationAPI.kt:190)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.RPCApi$ClientToServer$RpcRequest.writeToClientMessage(RPCApi.kt:113)
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.networkMapSnapshot(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Do any other types of RPC operations work (e.g. `protocolVersion`)?

Comment: It's working with protocolVersion. I get protocolVersion as 2.
though enabled trace logs and found exceptions:
T 19:30:42 1 Topology.<init> - Topology@4ef782af CREATE
 java.lang.Exception: trace
 at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.Topology.<init>(Topology.java:83) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
 at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.Topology.<init>(Topology.java:71) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
 at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.<init>(ServerLocatorImpl.java:435)

Comment: tried to get a state using vault query. got a buffer underflow exception:
E 19:49:57+0530 [Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] core.client.run - AMQ214000: Failed to call onMessage
 com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer underflow.
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.require(Input.java:199) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readBoolean(Input.java:801) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at de.javakaffee.kryoserializers.BitSetSerializer.read(BitSetSerializer.java:39) ~[kryo-serializers-0.41.jar:?]
        at

Comment: Are you able to link to a repository with the server code? I can't replicate the issue. I think it might be an issue related to a class not being present on the classpath.

Comment: I just witnessed something really strange. I created the whole project in eclipse. Had some trouble though but I like eclipse. It's just switched to intellij and created a template client to check if I get any error guess what no errors! The node has been running all the time. I didn't do a deploy Nodes again Just did the test on the same running nodes. and it works!. Both Clients are exactly same in eclipse and intellij. I even deleted .gradle folder. restarted eclipse and tried. java version is same in both, eclipse client still gives error while intellij's works..This is really strange.

Answer (score 2):

This can be fixed by clearing local caches.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that and explain why this happened and what are the exact steps to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162347/using-corda-rpc-api-in-spring-boot-throws-illegalargumentexception?noredirect=1&lq=1), this may be related to a conflict with google Guava library. Corda 3 uses Guava 21. In my case, my build.gradle did not explicitly have a Guava statement but my version of jHipster was using Guava 27. I simply added the following to the end of the dependencies on my build.gradle and it fixed the issue.

```
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '21.0'
```