# Quasar errors when running Spring server with Corda

Tags: spring, corda, quasar

I'm running a pretty hefty version of Spring (jHipster generated) in accordance with my Corda project. I'm getting some quasar related errors when I run the spring server. I'm guessing this is because quasar-utils is in the server's gradle dependencies. Quasar is complaining about something related to an OAuth2 spring service. I am actually not using any OAuth features so far, so I'm not sure if these errors are benign or not. Regardless, I'm a little concerned about quasar interfering in general. Is there a way to do RPC interactions with Corda without having quasar-utils in the server gradle dependencies?

Here are the errors:

```
[quasar] WARNING: Can't determine super class of org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/BindAuthenticator
[quasar] WARNING: Can't determine super class of org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/PasswordComparisonAuthenticator
2018-08-06 17:55:04.769 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByLogin      : Initialize successful.
2018-08-06 17:55:04.801 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByEmail      : Initialize successful.
[quasar] WARNING: Can't determine super class of org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/oidc/userinfo/OidcUserService
[quasar] WARNING: Can't determine super class of org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/userinfo/OAuth2UserService
[quasar] ERROR: Unable to instrument class org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/client/OAuth2LoginConfigurer
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.Item.a(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassWriter.c(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassWriter.a(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.commons.JSRInlinerAdapter.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.MethodVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.InstrumentClass$1.visitEnd(InstrumentClass.java:190)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.QuasarInstrumentor.instrumentClass(QuasarInstrumentor.java:134)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.QuasarInstrumentor.instrumentClass(QuasarInstrumentor.java:94)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.JavaAgent$Transformer.transform(JavaAgent.java:209)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:321)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:92)
    at com.cordatemplate.cordapp.config.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c1c18162.init(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bc81b89d.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$4(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bc81b89d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6a532806.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bc81b89d.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>:65535)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at com.cordatemplate.cordapp.CordaApp.main(CordaApp.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
[quasar] ERROR: while transforming org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/client/OAuth2LoginConfigurer: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.Item.a(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassWriter.c(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassWriter.a(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.commons.JSRInlinerAdapter.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.MethodVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.InstrumentClass$1.visitEnd(InstrumentClass.java:190)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.QuasarInstrumentor.instrumentClass(QuasarInstrumentor.java:134)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.QuasarInstrumentor.instrumentClass(QuasarInstrumentor.java:94)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.JavaAgent$Transformer.transform(JavaAgent.java:209)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:321)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:92)
    at com.cordatemplate.cordapp.config.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c1c18162.init(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bc81b89d.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$4(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bc81b89d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6a532806.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bc81b89d.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>:65535)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at com.cordatemplate.cordapp.CordaApp.main(CordaApp.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

Comment: Are you applying the Corda Quasar plugin to your node webserver (see https://github.com/corda/spring-webserver/blob/release-V3/build.gradle#L39)? What happens if you don't apply this plugin?

Comment: Yes I am applying the plugin. If I remove that line from my build.gradle, the app launches without the error -- however, I'll get a separate error about prviacy salts (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48578603/using-spring-boot-for-replacing-corda-server-giving-privacy-salt-should-be-32-bi). I tried clearing cache, but the issue remains. If I replace the quasar-utils plugin, the privacy salt error goes away and the original error returns.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you aren't using any of the objects that Quasar couldn't instrument inside flows you won't have any problems with it. Quasar is primarily used in Corda for suspendable fibres, which means a serialised stack. If the object isn't present on said stack it shouldn't cause any problems.

But more importantly; your Corda node and Spring Boot application should run in separate processes to avoid any interference. You only need Quasar utils when compiling Cordapps and Corda itself. If your Spring boot app is separate then I'd recommend building it in a separate gradle/maven subproject without a dependency on quasar-utils.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but looking at the sourcecode of `quasar-utils` [here](https://github.com/corda/corda-gradle-plugins/blob/release/4.0.45/quasar-utils/src/main/groovy/net/corda/plugins/QuasarPlugin.groovy#L41), you can set an extension prop for ignored packages in the **root** build:

```
ext.quasar_exclusions = [
        'co.paralleluniverse**',
        'groovy**',
        'com.esotericsoftware.**',
        'jdk**',
        'junit**',
        'kotlin**',
        'net.rubygrapefruit.**',
        'org.gradle.**',
        'org.apache.**',
        'org.jacoco.**',
        'org.junit**',
        'org.slf4j**',
        'worker.org.gradle.**',
        'com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin**',
        'org.assertj**',
        'org.hamcrest**',
        'org.mockito**',
        'org.opentest4j**',
        'org.springframework**',
        'reactor.core.publisher**',
        'com.github.manosbatsis.corbeans.spring.boot**'
]
```

additionally, it looks like [release 4.0.45](https://github.com/corda/corda-gradle-plugins/releases/tag/release%2F4.0.45) allows for a `quasar` extension like:

```
quasar {
    /// ...
    // defaults to quasar_exclusions property
    excludePackages = [
        'glob for package not to be instrumented',
        //...
    ]
}
```